# Is it a good or bad idea for a video player to have the play button in the top-left corner?

Tags: usability, video, pattern-recognition

Do you think it is a good or bad idea, and why? Also, why do you think Comedy Central (e.g., [The Daily Show](http://www.thecomedynetwork.ca/Shows/TheDailyShow)) put their play button in the top-left corner instead of the middle?

[image]

Comment: Is it truly the play button, or just an icon that represents what will happen when you click anywhere in the video?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey The fact that you're not sure is sign enough that something not-right is going on.

Comment: @Racheet, that depends on the goal of the original question. Many "play" buttons that appear transposed over the video aren't really buttons - clicking anywhere in the video plays (or pauses). The fact that this is up in the corner doesn't immediately imply a "not-right" situation.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I don't think the fact it's up in the corner is what signals a not-right situation, it's that there someone who isn't instantly sure what it does. That means to me that there's definitely room for improvement.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey though "room for improvement" doesn't mean that "what's there now isn't good enough".

Comment: This question is asking for pure speculation and therefore is not a good fit for a Q&A site such as this.

Comment: I don't think this question is really easy to answer. For one, maybe the object the button is alligned to is wrongly defined and thus null (code wise). This would also result in a button on the top left..

Comment: The real question, why THEY did it can only be asnwered by themselves. The question if this is a good idea is something else.

Comment: I can rephrase the question: «Do you think is a good or bad idea to ... and why?» No?

Comment: @Benoit Meunier: I think that would be a good idea. Or even make it an open question. "What is the best position for the play icon and why?" Then referring to 2 different examples (comedy central and YouTube).

Comment: @BartGijssens I'm not interested about the best position but if it's a good or a bad idea.

Comment: @BenoitMeunier: It's only a good idea if it's the best position. In all other cases it's a bad idea.

Comment: Something feels very unnatural about that.  I'm not sure why - since we're trained to read to the left and down and start at the top-left.  But we've also had these Media UI layouts so deeply ingrained into our DNA, that it's hard to imagine any other way (which may be a good reason to introduce something ... extreme).  It might be worth taking a step back and trying to learn where this layout that we're used to originated from.  Look at a Google Images search for "movie player UI" and it's shocking how little things differ between these apps (sure, icons, fonts etc look diff).

Comment: @AdamPlocher: It's probably related to the way that in music, almost anything other than a whole-measure rest should appear left-to-right in a measure, but whole-measure rests are centered.  Likewise, if there's only one thing on a page it should be centered, but when there are multiple things then they should start at the upper left.

Answer (score 7):

When looking at an image, the user tends to start from the center as it's the main focus point. I would opt to put the play button in the middle to ensure that the user knows its not a picture and it is a video. By putting the play button at the bottom the user may think its a picture.

Youtube (which one would argue is the most well known online video site) puts the play button in the middle, so one would assume that most users would be expecting this.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. If you've started watching the content, and then pause, the play button should be centered, and the video image could be darkened to show it's inactive.

I tried taking a look at the site, but as I'm European it won't let me see the actual video. What I did see though, was a bunch of thumbnails/links. And in those cases, yeah, I understand they moved the arrow. Compare their solution with a mockup of centered triangle:

[image]

In half the cases the triangle covers up a face. 75%, if we count Batman. That both makes the face unrecognizable, and it makes the triangle harder to read clearly. By moving the icon to a corner, you have much less interference between the focal point of the video/shot, and the triangle indicator.

The same logic would apply to a large video (before watching). Moving the triangle keeps the center of the image clean, which makes for a  much nicer looking page. And if they do keep the triangle in the corner as play/pause indicator, that's for internal consistency.

As for why the top-left corner; western cultures read left-to-right and top-to-bottom, so it's the first corner we look at.

As a sidenote; have you ever paid close attention to YouTube? On search pages and channel listings the triangle isn't anywhere to be found. It's only on actual videos. YouTube doesn't *need* the triangle to signify that something's a video, because it's a video site.

This site doesn't *quite* have the same affordance (all content on this site is video) but it has a similar affordance; the daily show is a TV/video show.

In short:

- the triangle should not be the button (the whole screen should be a big play/pause button)
- moving the triangle makes the frame/site look better
- moving the triangle makes the triangle stand out more.
- this site has less need to point out that a video is a video as it's the main content type